How do I use "OnDisconnected" in Unity Photon?
I'm studying to connect to a photon server in Unity, but when I shut down a photon server with a forced shutdown or a button
I'm trying to get the code to run at the bottom, and it works well with the OnLeftLobby callback function, but OnDisconnected
In the callback function, code cannot be executed and ends
    public void DisconnectedPhoton()
{
PhotonNetwork.Disconnect();
}

public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
{
    pv.RPC("LeftPhoton", RpcTarget.All, myPlayer.ViewID);
}


when you are disconnected - how do you expect an RPC to be submitted? o.O

When I shut down the Photon server in a multi-map, I want to delete all the data about the person I shut down, like List or Scene's Player

So when I connect the OnLeftLobby function to the button as a test, "pv.RPC("LeftPhoton", RpcTarget.All, myPlayer.ViewID);" works well, but if I connect to the function like the code above and exit, It will not be removed from the list, It's processed to missing

Sounds like you would rather want to use OnPlayerLeftRoom ... when you get your own OnDisconnected .. well you can't use Photon network anymore because you are disconnected ;) The others shall rather react to your disconnect which is what OnPlayerLeftRoom is about: If another player leaves the room or if the server detects a lost connection, this callback will be used to notify your game logic.

I see. Thank you very much. Then would you tell me when it's good to use "OnDisconnected()"??

When you want to track whether yourself disconnected.. for example to switch to a different scene or show some error messages to the user ... and for instance some UI to reconnect

Use the OnPlayerLeftRoom function, which includes the player that left.  This gets called whenever a player left the room (disconnected) or became inactive (if you game supports it).  When a connected player receives this callback, have them clean up the local objects belonging to the disconnected player.
// This function is called on all connected clients when a player disconnects or becomes inactive
//
void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
{
    if (otherPlayer.IsInactive)
    {
        // Player is inactive, allow them to rejoin or handle some other way
    }
    else
    {
        // Clean up the disconnected players objects
    }
}

Note: If the player is not inactive, the player that left will not be in the Room.Players dictionary by the time this callback happens.
